# Gemfire EntryNotFoundException for @CacheEvict

Tags: java, spring, caching, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

In short, when @CacheEvict is called on a method and if the key for the entry is not found, Gemfire is throwing EntryNotFoundException.

Now in detail,

I have a class

```
class Person {

 String mobile;
 int dept;
 String name;

}
```

I have two Cache regions defined as personRegion and personByDeptRegion and the Service is as below

```
@Service
class PersonServiceImpl {

   @Cacheable(value = "personRegion")
   public Person findByMobile(String mobile) {

      return personRepository.findByMobile(mobile);

   }


   @Cacheable(value = "personByDeptRegion")
   public List<Person> findByDept(int deptCode) {

      return personRepository.findByDept(deptCode);

   }


   @Caching(
      evict = { @CacheEvict(value = "personByDeptRegion", key="#p0.dept"},
      put = { @CachePut(value = "personRegion",key = "#p0.mobile")}

   )
   public Person updatePerson(Person p1) {

      return personRepository.save(p1);

   }

}
```

When there is a call to updatePerson and if there are no entries in the personByDeptRegion, this would throw an exception that EntryNotFoundException for the key 1 ( or whatever is the dept code ). There is a very good chance that this method will be called before the @Cacheable methods are called and want to avoid this exception.
Is there any way we could tweak the Gemfire behavior to gracefully return when the key is not existing for a given region ?. 
Alternatively, I am also eager to know if there is a better implementation of the above scenario using Gemfire as cache.

Spring Data Gemfire : 1.7.4

Gemfire Version     : v8.2.1

Note: The above code is for representation purpose only and I have multiple services with same issue in actual project.

Comment: Wow! You should consider upgrading your version of SDG!  1.3.5.RELEASE? o.O  You realize `1.8.4.RELEASE` is the most current version (based on GF 8.2.0).  1.7.6.RELEASE is the currently supported maintenance version (based on GF 8.1.0).  And, SDG 1.9 is currently in development, with a 1.9 M1 already available and 1.9 GA scheduled for December 12th.  You can stay informed by viewing the SDG project page (http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/) ...

Comment: ... as well as taking a look at the project compatibility matrix Wiki page (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/wiki/Spring-Data-GemFire-to-GemFire-Version-Compatibility).  Also, you can view release details on the SD Wiki page (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki); see Nav column to the right.  Current releases are Gosling (SDG 1.7.6.RELEASE) & Hopper (SDG 1.8.4.RELEASE).  Ingalls (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Ingalls) is up and coming.

Comment: Having said this... I will follow up with a "answer" to your question in a bit.

Comment: I am extremely sorry John, I put the version of spring boot instead of SDG :(
SDG version is 1.7.4
Have updated in the question as well. We will be moving to spring boot 1.4.1 soon , so I believe that will bring in 1.8 of SDG :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I commend you for using *Spring's* Caching annotations on your application `@Service` components.  All too often developers enable caching in their Repositories, which I think is bad form, especially if complex business rules (or even additional IO; e.g. calling a web service from a service component) are involved prior to or after the Repository interaction(s), particularly in cases where caching behavior should not be affected (or determined).

I also think your caching UC (updating one cache (`personRegion`) while invalidating another (`personByDeptRegion`) on a data store update) by following a `CachePut` with a `CacheEvict` seems reasonable to me.  Though, I would point out that the seemingly intended use of the `@Caching` annotation is to combine multiple Caching annotations of the **same** type (e.g. multiple `@CacheEvict` or multiple `@CachePut`) as explained in the core *Spring Framework* [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotations-caching).  Still, there is nothing preventing your intended use.

I created a similar test class [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithGemFireIntegrationTest.java), modeled after your example above, to verify the problem.  Indeed the [jonDoeUpdateSuccessful](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithGemFireIntegrationTest.java#L132-L139) test case fails (with the GemFire `EntryNotFoundException`, shown below) since no people in `Department` "R&D" were previously cached in the "`DepartmentPeople`" GemFire Region prior to the update, unlike the [janeDoeUpdateSuccessful](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithGemFireIntegrationTest.java#L120-L130) test case, which causes the cache to be populated before the update (even if the entry has no values, which is of no consequence).

```
com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.EntryNotFoundException: RESEARCH_DEVELOPMENT
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractRegionMap.destroy(AbstractRegionMap.java:1435)
```

> NOTE: My test uses GemFire as both a "cache provider" and a System of Record (SOR).

The problem really lies in SDG's use of [Region.destroy(key)](http://data-docs-samples.cfapps.io/docs-gemfire/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/Region.html#destroy(java.lang.Object)) in the [GemfireCache.evict(key)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/1.8.4.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/support/GemfireCache.java#L65-L67) implementation rather than, and perhaps more appropriately, [Region.remove(key)](http://data-docs-samples.cfapps.io/docs-gemfire/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/Region.html#remove(java.lang.Object)).

`GemfireCache.evict(key)` has been implemented with `Region.destroy(key)` since inception.  However, `Region.remove(key)` was not introduced until GemFire v5.0.  Still, I can see no discernible difference between `Region.destroy(key)` and `Region.remove(key)` other than the `EntryNotFoundException` thrown by `Region.destroy(key)`.  Essentially, they both destroy the local entry (both key and value) as well as distribute the operation to other caches in the cluster (providing a non-`LOCAL` [Scope](http://data-docs-samples.cfapps.io/docs-gemfire/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/Scope.html#LOCAL) is used).

So, I have filed [SGF-539](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-539) to change SDG to call `Region.remove(key)` in `GemfireCache.evict(key)` rather than `Region.destroy(key)`.

As for a workaround, well, there is basically only 2 things you can do:

1. Restructure your code and your use of the `@CacheEvict` annotation, and/or...
2. Make use of the `condition` on `@CacheEvict`.

It is unfortunate that a `condition` cannot be specified using a class type, something akin to a *Spring* [Condition](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html) (in addition to SpEL), but this interface is intended for another purpose and the `@CacheEvict`, `condition` attribute does not accept a class type.

At the moment, I don't have a good example of how this might work so I am moving forward on [SGF-539](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-539).

You can following this ticket for more details and progress.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

-John

Comment: @Sandheep - I have great news... I figured out a workaround for you until I have SGF-539 resolved.  See my update test class example (https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithGemFireIntegrationTest.java#L146-L167) for more details.

Comment: Note, the key to the "workaround" is this... https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithGemFireIntegrationTest.java#L157 (exactly the change to SDG that needs to be made)... ;-)

Comment: Excellcent John :). Thank you so much for creating the ticket and especially for the immediate workaround. Was kind of stuck with this. Will test the workaround and  let you know.

Comment: Hi Sandheep- 1 last update.  I resolved/fixed SGF-539.  It has been committed to `1.7.x` (for Gosling 1.7.7.RELEASE), `1.8.x` (for Hopper 1.8.5.RELEASE), `apache-geode` and `master` (for Ingalls 1.9 RC1).  Unfortunately, SDG 1.7.6 and 1.8.4 maintenance releases just went out and 1.7.7/1.8.5 are not scheduled for sometime.  1.9 RC1 is scheduled for the end of Nov with the final 1.9 GA on 12/12.  The workaround worked flawlessly in my example test class.  If you have problems let me know.  Cheers!

Comment: Spot on :)
I tried the  workaround and its working fine.
One thing though, I have a GemfireConfig class annotated with @Configuration. When I added the CacheManager as a bean in this class, the first time after startup of application gave same error and subsequent calls were working ( Confirmed that in both the cases the list cache was empty ). 
Then I moved the  bean definition to a dedicated class and GemfireConfig having other region definitions. This seems to fix the first run issue. I am not exactly sure about the cause. But seems to be something to do with the order of bean creation.